# Marble - Updating a Placemark Style

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, marble

I'm using Marble C++ in a Qt application, and I'm having trouble updating a placemark style after I upgraded to Marble 15.12. In 15.08, it worked simply by setting a new icon path for the GeoDataIconStyle, setting the new style of the GeoDataStyle, and then updating the GeoDataPlacemark through the MapWidget tree model. This would be the typical way before to update the icon:

```
icon->setIcon( QImage("icon_path") );'
style->setIconStyle( *icon );
MarbleWidget->model()->treeModel()->updateFeature( placeMark );
```

After changing the style to a QSharedPointer reflecting the current API, I tried to change the icons like before. But the icon would only change when the current MapWidget view was moved out of the scope of the placemark by panning with the mouse. Does anyone have an idea of what might be the issue?

One thing to mention is the paint layers is not what I'm looking for, as I need these placemarks to be mouse-clickable. Thanks so much for your time.